# CiviCRM: access AJAX API not respected in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, permissions, apiv4

CiviCRM 5.58.1, vanilla WordPress 6.1.1  with the default theme.

Both **CiviCRM: access AJAX API**  and **CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API** are checked. Still, executing
`CRM.api4('Contact', 'autocomplete', {input: term}).then(function(result) {`

works only for  "administrator" role. Anonymous gets redirected to

```
wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.site%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3DCiviCRM%26q%3Dcivicrm%252Fajax%252Fapi4%252FContact%252Fautocomplete&reauth=1
```

Moreover, even if ALL "CiviCRM: administer CiviCRM{system,data}" and "Skip IDs check"  permissons   granted to anonymous, the system still redirects to wp_login.php

Where and how to loose this a bit? Anonymous would like to search for Contacts in Civi database!

Comment: Do you have Authx ext enabled?

Comment: No I don't,  should I?

Comment: Have it enabled and disabled all guards - still no response from API call for anonymous.